# How to add Categories and other such properties to application settings (In vb.net)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Ok, so I have this PropertyGrid Control that displays all my (User) Application Settings and that's all cool and everything, But I wanted my settings to be sorted into Categories and have Descriptions etc.

So I looked around and worked out that if I inserted the following code:

```
Global.System.ComponentModel.Category("Category Name :D")
Global.System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Display Name")
Global.System.ComponentModel.Description("whatevs")
```

into to each Property in the Settings.Designer.vb file like this:

```
    '''<summary>
    '''This Setting dose some stuff
    '''</summary>
    <Global.System.ComponentModel.Category("Category Name :D"), _
     Global.System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Display Name"), _
     Global.System.ComponentModel.Description("whatevs"), _
     Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(), _
     Global.System.Configuration.SettingsDescriptionAttribute("This Setting dose some stuff"), _
     Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
     Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Stuff")> _
    Public Property FOLDER_OutputRealm() As String
        Get
            Return CType(Me("Stuff_Setting"), String)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me("Stuff_Setting") = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

I would get what I wanted, That is until I change something in my settings and cause the Settings.Designer.vb file to regenerate, Thus Losing all my custom changes.

What is the Proper way to assign Categories/DisplayNames/Descriptions to the application settings in VB.NET?

Comment: you can add in listview  or make global value ...

Comment: But PropertyGrid Control is way cooler~

Comment: Is coolness part of the requirements spec?

Comment: Damn right it is. And besides, adding categories & descriptions to app settings seems like something you should totally be able to do.